# Background service to play CDs without being logged in

Tags: fedora, audio, data-cd

Before I reinvent wheel, is there currently a background service that can detect when a CD is inserted and if it is an audio CD, mount it and execute a command to play it without being logged in.

I'm running Fedora 22, with lightdm as desktop manager (so if there's something plugin for lightdm that'll work too, I'm just trying to make this super easy for my wife and not leave a terminal up and running unnecessarily), she'd probably be kind of annoyed if she can't skip tracks, but I could probably figure something out to make that work.

My next easiest solution would just be to have a CD player only login user who automatically mounts and plays the CD, but if that could be done without user intervention, I think it would be a bit better.

Third best solution would be to switch to a terminal and run some command line vlc player or something.

So, what I'd like to know is A. if something already exists and B. is the most direct way to figure out if someone inserted a CD to make a service and wait for someone to put in a CD?

Comment: Can [mpd](http://www.musicpd.org/) do this?

Comment: @user looks [like it can](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/input_plugins.html)